# estimating Threshold-Models in seperate equations

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model, threshold

I´m currently dealing with threshold VECM models in time series. The basic idea behind a TVECM, according to [Lo and Zivot 2001](ftp://ftp.soc.uoc.gr/students/aslanidis/My%20documents/papers/Lo%20&%20Zivot%20(2001).pdf) is

[image: TVECM]

There is one point I don´t understand: As far as I see every coefficient is regime specific (including beta). So shouldn´t it be possible to just split the sample between the two regimes and estimate two separate normal VECMs? 
(I´m pretty sure that is wrong but I can´t find an proper explanation for this)